# Android - Receive Push notification and display it - not quite understanding

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Ok so I finally got setup to register devices for push notifications. I found this code to receive new notifications and display it. Thing is I'm not sure where it goes. I'm pretty new to Android programming so any help is appreciated. 
I have a service class called GCMService below.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMService";

    public GCMService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId= " + regId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String regId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }
}
```

**Where does the function below go in relation to my class above to receive a new message?**

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);      

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, LauncherActivity.class);

      PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; 
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling your notification generate where the notifications arrive - GCMService.onMessage()?

Comment: I figured that might be what is needed however do I call generateNotification() just inside the onMessage? what about the parameters? e.g. generateNotification(something here, something here); what would I put there?

Comment: oh nevermind, whoa I think I got it. I'm starting to feel retarded, a function should work the same regardless of language. I'll try it and let and see. that's what happens when you just copy and paste. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I finally found a pretty good working project for which you can study the code and understand it. It took me days of googling to find something that wasn't just a piece here and a piece there but instead a whole project. I figured I'd be nice enough to post it in case someone else could use it.

https://github.com/Guti/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code it's properly work:

```
@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {

    sendNotification("Message Deleted On server");
    super.onDeletedMessages();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    sendNotification("Received: " + data.getString("message"));
    super.onMessageReceived(from, data);
}

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {

    sendNotification("Message Sent: " + msgId);
    super.onMessageSent(msgId);
}

@Override
public void onSendError(String msgId, String error) {

    sendNotification("Message Sent Error: " + msgId + "Error: " + error);
    super.onSendError(msgId, error);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageView.class);
    intent.putExtra("Message", msg);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_y)
            .setContentTitle("CCD Message").setContentText(msg)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```