# android- receive the push notification text and display it in activity

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am able to send push notification from "Parse" (3rd party). But, when user receives that message, I want to receive that message in some string and display it in some Activity. I used the following default code of "Parse" to go to some activity after clicking on notification

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, PushNoti.class);//change the class where u want to go after clicking on noti
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

By using it I am able go to that activity too, but can anyone help me in getting that text in some string and display it? Or, is there any default method which gets called after clicking on notification? (as in iOS)

Please do not consider this post as duplicate of [Android - Receive Push notification and display it - not quite understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996695/android-receive-push-notification-and-display-it-not-quite-understanding) as I am not using titanium.

Answer (score 4):

The way to reach all the json data of the notification inside the started Activity is:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
String jsonData = extras.getString( "com.parse.Data" );
Log.d("MyApp",jsonData);
```

Comment: hi this solution is correct but if we have more than 1 pushes and we clicking one by one then this solution not give correct message .

Comment: If a regular notification is sent and my app is in background, extras DO NOT contain title and body of the notification. It only contains the data part.